# CISCO ASR 1006 , RP1 disabled

Tags: cisco

I have an issue with a Cisco ASR 1006 router.
I get these error messages:

```
%IOSXEBOOT-4-BOOT_ACTIVITY_LONG_TIME: (rp/0): load_crash_kernel took: 2 seconds, expected max time 2 seconds
%IOSXEBOOT-4-FILESYS_ERRORS_CORRECTED: (rp/0): bootflash 1 contained errors which were auto-corrected.
%IOSXEBOOT-4-FILESYS_ERRORS_CORRECTED: (rp/0): harddisk 1 contained errors which were auto-corrected.
%IOSXEBOOT-4-BOOT_ACTIVITY_LONG_TIME: (rp/0): prep_storage took: 16 seconds, expected max time 10 seconds
%IOSXEBOOT-4-BOOT_SRC: (rp/0): Non-HD Boot
```

The second card processor is disabled :

```
Router#sh platform
Chassis type: ASR1006

Slot      Type                State                 Insert time (ago)
--------- ------------------- --------------------- -----------------
0                             disabled              00:14:15
R0        ASR1000-RP1         ok, active            00:14:15
R1                            disabled              00:14:15
F0        ASR1000-ESP10       ok, active            00:14:15
F1        ASR1000-ESP10       ok, standby           00:14:15
P0        ASR1006-PWR-AC      ok                    00:12:52
P1        ASR1006-PWR-AC      ok                    00:12:51

Slot      CPLD Version        Firmware Version
--------- ------------------- ---------------------------------------
0         N/A                 N/A
R0        11060317            15.3(3r)S
R1        N/A                 N/A
F0        09111601            15.3(3r)S
F1        09111601            15.3(3r)S

Router#
```

Please help.

Comment: Sounds like a memory problem. Try reloading the OS. If that doesn’t work, you may have a bad chip.

Comment: I did  reloading it several times , but doesn't work. Thanx .

Comment: Have you opened a Cisco TAC case yet?